# Add link to buttons Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello so I'm new to coding and I downloaded a menu thing to test but I cannot find how to add links? The code works fine but I don't get how to add links to the buttons haha thanks for the help. I'm pretty new to javascript but I can do some HTML if that's whats needed. When button pressed it changes to index.html# Thats all that happens. And im wondering if somone can help me thanks a lot!

```js
var links = [{label: '10A', bg: '#c0392b'}, 
             {label: '10B', bg: '#16a085'}, 
             {label: '10C', bg: '#8e44ad'}, 
             {label: '10D', bg: '#27ae60'}];
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
if(windowHeight === 0) windowHeight = 238;
var radius = windowHeight*0.6,
    circle = document.createElement('div'),
    borderSize = radius*0.021;
    totalArea = 48, 
    increment = totalArea/(links.length-1),
    startPoint = 0-(totalArea/2),
    fontSize = radius*0.12,
    linkSize = radius*0.25;

styleCircle();
addCircle();
addLinks();
styleLinks();

function styleCircle() {
  circle.style.border= borderSize+'px solid #fff';
  circle.style.width = radius*2+'px';
  circle.style.height = radius*2+'px';
  circle.style.borderRadius = radius+'px';
  circle.style.position = 'absolute';
  circle.style.top = '-'+radius*0.2+'px';
  circle.style.left = radius*-1+'px';
}

function addCircle() {
  document.body.appendChild(circle);
}

function addLinks() {
  for (var i=0, l=links.length; i<l; i++) {
    link = document.createElement('a'),
    hover = document.createElement('span');
    link.href = "#";
    link.dataset.color = links[i].bg;
    link.style.display = 'inline-block';
    link.style.textDecoration = 'none';
    link.style.color = '#fff';
    link.style.position = 'absolute';
    link.style.zIndex = 100;
    link.innerHTML = links[i].label;
    hover.style.position = 'absolute';
    hover.style.display = 'inline-block';
    hover.style.zIndex = 50;
    hover.style.opacity = 0;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    document.body.appendChild(hover);
    link.addEventListener('mouseover', linkOver);
    link.addEventListener('mouseout', linkOut);
    links[i].elem = link;
    links[i].hover = hover;
  }
}

function styleLinks() {
  for (var i=0, l=links.length; i<l; i++) {
    var link = links[i].elem, hover = links[i].hover, deg = startPoint+(i*increment);  
    link.style.paddingLeft = radius*1.2+'px';
    link.style.fontSize = fontSize+'px';
    link.style.height = linkSize+'px';
    link.style.lineHeight = linkSize+'px';
    setTransformOrigin(link, '0px '+linkSize*0.5+'px');
    setTransition(link, 'all 0.2s ease-out');
    setTransform(link, 'rotate('+deg+'deg)');
    link.style.left = borderSize+'px';
    link.style.top = (windowHeight/2) - (windowHeight*0.1)+borderSize+'px';

    hover.style.left = borderSize+'px';
    setTransformOrigin(hover, '0px '+linkSize*0.5+'px');
    setTransition(hover, 'all 0.2s ease-out');
    setTransform(hover, 'rotate('+deg+'deg)');
    hover.style.top = (windowHeight*0.4)+borderSize +'px';
    hover.style.width = radius+(borderSize/2)+'px';
    hover.style.height = linkSize+'px';
    hover.style.borderRight = borderSize*2+'px solid #fff';
  
  }
}

window.onresize = function() {
  windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  radius = windowHeight*0.6,
  borderSize = radius*0.021;  
  fontSize = radius*0.12,
  linkSize = radius*0.25;
  styleCircle();
  styleLinks();
}

function linkOver(e) {
  var thisLink = e.target, thisHover = thisLink.nextSibling;
  thisLink.style.paddingLeft = radius*1.25+'px';
  thisHover.style.opacity = 1;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = thisLink.dataset.color;
}

function linkOut(e) {
  var thisLink = e.target, thisHover = thisLink.nextSibling;
  thisLink.style.paddingLeft = radius*1.2+'px';
  thisHover.style.opacity = 0;
}

function setTransform(element, string) {
  element.style.webkitTransform = string;
  element.style.MozTransform = string;
  element.style.msTransform = string;
  element.style.OTransform = string;
  element.style.transform = string;
}

function setTransformOrigin(element, string) {
  element.style.webkitTransformOrigin = string;
  element.style.MozTransformOrigin = string;
  element.style.msTransformOrigin = string;
  element.style.OTransformOrigin = string;
  element.style.transformOrigin = string;
}

function setTransition(element, string) {
  element.style.webkitTransition = string;
  element.style.MozTransition = string;
  element.style.msTransition = string;
  element.style.OTransition = string;
  element.style.transition = string;
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Economica:400,700);

body {
  background: #c0392b;
  font-family: 'Economica', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#circle {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: -250px;
}
```

Comment: If you are new, don't download code, learn why writing your own code and by trying to create smaller things.

Comment: Il do that next time just wanted to try it.

Comment: You already added links, but they all ref to `#` Change the line `link.href = "#";`

Comment: `link.href = "#";` suppose to contain url. look here
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/A

Comment: But there is only one href but 4 links?

Answer (score 1):

In your "addLinks" function, you set the link href property:

```
link.href = "#";
```

Just change it to whatever you want:

```
link.href = 'https://google.fr';
```

To answer your comment about several links. You can store your links in an array:

```
var myArray = ['https://first-link.com', '/mylink', 'yet-another-link'];
```

The for loop will define each link. I is the index of the link:

```
for (var i=0, l=links.length; i<l; i++) {
}
```

You can use it to set the right path to each link:

```
for (var i=0, l=links.length; i<l; i++) {
    ...(some code here)...
    link.href = myArray[i];
}
```

Comment: But i want it to be difrent sites on each button how do i do that?

Comment: I answered in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

because you downloaded the code and did not know how it was working, and did not change the required things. 
1-you have to define href in links array,

```
var links = [{label: '10A', bg: '#c0392b',url:'aaa'}, 
         {label: '10B', bg: '#16a085',url:'bbb'}, 
         {label: '10C', bg: '#8e44ad', url:'ccc'}, 
         {label: '10D', bg: '#27ae60',url: 'ddd'}];
```

2- and then add them .  `link.href =  links[i].href;`

```js
var links = [{label: '10A', bg: '#c0392b',url:'aaa'}, 
             {label: '10B', bg: '#16a085',href:'bbb'}, 
             {label: '10C', bg: '#8e44ad', href:'ccc'}, 
             {label: '10D', bg: '#27ae60',href : 'ddd'}];
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
if(windowHeight === 0) windowHeight = 238;
var radius = windowHeight*0.6,
    circle = document.createElement('div'),
    borderSize = radius*0.021;
    totalArea = 48, 
    increment = totalArea/(links.length-1),
    startPoint = 0-(totalArea/2),
    fontSize = radius*0.12,
    linkSize = radius*0.25;

styleCircle();
addCircle();
addLinks();
styleLinks();

function styleCircle() {
  circle.style.border= borderSize+'px solid #fff';
  circle.style.width = radius*2+'px';
  circle.style.height = radius*2+'px';
  circle.style.borderRadius = radius+'px';
  circle.style.position = 'absolute';
  circle.style.top = '-'+radius*0.2+'px';
  circle.style.left = radius*-1+'px';
}

function addCircle() {
  document.body.appendChild(circle);
}

function addLinks() {
  for (var i=0, l=links.length; i<l; i++) {
    link = document.createElement('a'),
    hover = document.createElement('span');
    link.href =  links[i].url;
    link.dataset.color = links[i].bg;
    link.style.display = 'inline-block';
    link.style.textDecoration = 'none';
    link.style.color = '#fff';
    link.style.position = 'absolute';
    link.style.zIndex = 100;
    link.innerHTML = links[i].label;
    hover.style.position = 'absolute';
    hover.style.display = 'inline-block';
    hover.style.zIndex = 50;
    hover.style.opacity = 0;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    document.body.appendChild(hover);
    link.addEventListener('mouseover', linkOver);
    link.addEventListener('mouseout', linkOut);
    links[i].elem = link;
    links[i].hover = hover;
  }
}

function styleLinks() {
  for (var i=0, l=links.length; i<l; i++) {
    var link = links[i].elem, hover = links[i].hover, deg = startPoint+(i*increment);  
    link.style.paddingLeft = radius*1.2+'px';
    link.style.fontSize = fontSize+'px';
    link.style.height = linkSize+'px';
    link.style.lineHeight = linkSize+'px';
    setTransformOrigin(link, '0px '+linkSize*0.5+'px');
    setTransition(link, 'all 0.2s ease-out');
    setTransform(link, 'rotate('+deg+'deg)');
    link.style.left = borderSize+'px';
    link.style.top = (windowHeight/2) - (windowHeight*0.1)+borderSize+'px';

    hover.style.left = borderSize+'px';
    setTransformOrigin(hover, '0px '+linkSize*0.5+'px');
    setTransition(hover, 'all 0.2s ease-out');
    setTransform(hover, 'rotate('+deg+'deg)');
    hover.style.top = (windowHeight*0.4)+borderSize +'px';
    hover.style.width = radius+(borderSize/2)+'px';
    hover.style.height = linkSize+'px';
    hover.style.borderRight = borderSize*2+'px solid #fff';
  
  }
}

window.onresize = function() {
  windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  radius = windowHeight*0.6,
  borderSize = radius*0.021;  
  fontSize = radius*0.12,
  linkSize = radius*0.25;
  styleCircle();
  styleLinks();
}

function linkOver(e) {
  var thisLink = e.target, thisHover = thisLink.nextSibling;
  thisLink.style.paddingLeft = radius*1.25+'px';
  thisHover.style.opacity = 1;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = thisLink.dataset.color;
}

function linkOut(e) {
  var thisLink = e.target, thisHover = thisLink.nextSibling;
  thisLink.style.paddingLeft = radius*1.2+'px';
  thisHover.style.opacity = 0;
}

function setTransform(element, string) {
  element.style.webkitTransform = string;
  element.style.MozTransform = string;
  element.style.msTransform = string;
  element.style.OTransform = string;
  element.style.transform = string;
}

function setTransformOrigin(element, string) {
  element.style.webkitTransformOrigin = string;
  element.style.MozTransformOrigin = string;
  element.style.msTransformOrigin = string;
  element.style.OTransformOrigin = string;
  element.style.transformOrigin = string;
}

function setTransition(element, string) {
  element.style.webkitTransition = string;
  element.style.MozTransition = string;
  element.style.msTransition = string;
  element.style.OTransition = string;
  element.style.transition = string;
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Economica:400,700);

body {
  background: #c0392b;
  font-family: 'Economica', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#circle {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: -250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code already created links. It's the `<a>` tag. But - your link all refer to `'#'` which leads to nowhere. Change them to a valid URL address.

In the code below, I created another array called `urls` which each of your links will lead to.

**note** stackoverflow's snipped prevent redirection, but the code will work you your environment.

```js
var links = [{label: '10A', bg: '#c0392b'}, 
             {label: '10B', bg: '#16a085'}, 
             {label: '10C', bg: '#8e44ad'}, 
             {label: '10D', bg: '#27ae60'}];

var urls = ['http://google.com',
            'http://example.com', 
            'http://foo.com', 
            'http://stackoverflow.com'];

var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
if(windowHeight === 0) windowHeight = 238;
var radius = windowHeight*0.6,
    circle = document.createElement('div'),
    borderSize = radius*0.021;
    totalArea = 48, 
    increment = totalArea/(links.length-1),
    startPoint = 0-(totalArea/2),
    fontSize = radius*0.12,
    linkSize = radius*0.25;

styleCircle();
addCircle();
addLinks();
styleLinks();

function styleCircle() {
  circle.style.border= borderSize+'px solid #fff';
  circle.style.width = radius*2+'px';
  circle.style.height = radius*2+'px';
  circle.style.borderRadius = radius+'px';
  circle.style.position = 'absolute';
  circle.style.top = '-'+radius*0.2+'px';
  circle.style.left = radius*-1+'px';
}

function addCircle() {
  document.body.appendChild(circle);
}

function addLinks() {
  for (var i=0, l=links.length; i<l; i++) {
    link = document.createElement('a'),
    hover = document.createElement('span');
    link.href = urls[i];
    link.dataset.color = links[i].bg;
    link.style.display = 'inline-block';
    link.style.textDecoration = 'none';
    link.style.color = '#fff';
    link.style.position = 'absolute';
    link.style.zIndex = 100;
    link.innerHTML = links[i].label;
    hover.style.position = 'absolute';
    hover.style.display = 'inline-block';
    hover.style.zIndex = 50;
    hover.style.opacity = 0;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    document.body.appendChild(hover);
    link.addEventListener('mouseover', linkOver);
    link.addEventListener('mouseout', linkOut);
    links[i].elem = link;
    links[i].hover = hover;
  }
}

function styleLinks() {
  for (var i=0, l=links.length; i<l; i++) {
    var link = links[i].elem, hover = links[i].hover, deg = startPoint+(i*increment);  
    link.style.paddingLeft = radius*1.2+'px';
    link.style.fontSize = fontSize+'px';
    link.style.height = linkSize+'px';
    link.style.lineHeight = linkSize+'px';
    setTransformOrigin(link, '0px '+linkSize*0.5+'px');
    setTransition(link, 'all 0.2s ease-out');
    setTransform(link, 'rotate('+deg+'deg)');
    link.style.left = borderSize+'px';
    link.style.top = (windowHeight/2) - (windowHeight*0.1)+borderSize+'px';

    hover.style.left = borderSize+'px';
    setTransformOrigin(hover, '0px '+linkSize*0.5+'px');
    setTransition(hover, 'all 0.2s ease-out');
    setTransform(hover, 'rotate('+deg+'deg)');
    hover.style.top = (windowHeight*0.4)+borderSize +'px';
    hover.style.width = radius+(borderSize/2)+'px';
    hover.style.height = linkSize+'px';
    hover.style.borderRight = borderSize*2+'px solid #fff';
  
  }
}

window.onresize = function() {
  windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  radius = windowHeight*0.6,
  borderSize = radius*0.021;  
  fontSize = radius*0.12,
  linkSize = radius*0.25;
  styleCircle();
  styleLinks();
}

function linkOver(e) {
  var thisLink = e.target, thisHover = thisLink.nextSibling;
  thisLink.style.paddingLeft = radius*1.25+'px';
  thisHover.style.opacity = 1;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = thisLink.dataset.color;
}

function linkOut(e) {
  var thisLink = e.target, thisHover = thisLink.nextSibling;
  thisLink.style.paddingLeft = radius*1.2+'px';
  thisHover.style.opacity = 0;
}

function setTransform(element, string) {
  element.style.webkitTransform = string;
  element.style.MozTransform = string;
  element.style.msTransform = string;
  element.style.OTransform = string;
  element.style.transform = string;
}

function setTransformOrigin(element, string) {
  element.style.webkitTransformOrigin = string;
  element.style.MozTransformOrigin = string;
  element.style.msTransformOrigin = string;
  element.style.OTransformOrigin = string;
  element.style.transformOrigin = string;
}

function setTransition(element, string) {
  element.style.webkitTransition = string;
  element.style.MozTransition = string;
  element.style.msTransition = string;
  element.style.OTransition = string;
  element.style.transition = string;
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Economica:400,700);

body {
  background: #c0392b;
  font-family: 'Economica', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#circle {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: -250px;
}
```